# I don't want my Android app to auto-update onto users devices

Tags: android

We're currently running tests (that end in 2 weeks) with clients using an "older" version of our app.

The older app has a long-running scanner foreground service that will *not* restart on the MY_PACKAGE_UPDATE broadcast (wasn't implemented at the time). The new version of the app correctly handles this broadcast and restarts the scanning on MY_PACKAGE_UPDATE.

We need to roll out updates mid-test to fix a bug appearing on only *some* devices, and we are able to reach out to those specific users. The problem is that for any current users with auto-update turned on, their foreground scanning service will exit and *not* restart.

1. Am I correct that the MY_PACKAGE_UPDATE broadcast won't kick in yet? As in, it'll only begin working two updates from now?
2. Is there a way for me to turn off auto-updating for my app in the play store for all users?

Comment: You can spread updates among particular group of users using beta testing in google play